# Nest.js validate array of strings if there are defined strings only

Tags: typescript, validation, request, nestjs

In the nest.js application on controller level I have to validate DTO.

I've faced with difficulty to check if item is not null (request should be rejected if any list item is `null` or `undefined`)

Code bellow demonstrates my configured verifications.

```
import { ArrayMinSize, IsArray } from 'class-validator'

export class ReminderPayload {
    // ...
    @IsArray()
    @ArrayMinSize(1)
    recipients: string[]
}
```

### Question

1. I'm looking for help to reject requests with body data like

```
{
    "recipients": [
        null
    ]
}
```

2. How to validate if array items are `string` only (it should reject handling if object is in the array item position)?

### P.S.

`'class-validator'` injected successfully, and it produces some validation results for my API.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You need to tell class-validator to run the validations on `each` item of the array.  Change your payload DTO to the following:

```
import { ArrayMinSize, IsArray, IsString } from 'class-validator';

export class ReminderPayloadDto {
  // ...
  @IsArray()
  // "each" tells class-validator to run the validation on each item of the array
  @IsString({ each: true })
  @ArrayMinSize(1)
  recipients: string[];
}
```

[Link](https://github.com/typestack/class-validator#validating-arrays) to the docs on this.

Comment: Brilliant! You've missed `@IsNotEmpty({ each: true })`, but I've got the idea and missed documentation part

Comment: @Sergii, I think IsString() will cover IsNotEmpty(). please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Mahmoud, @IsString() verifies only input value type. It fails if input value is number type for example.

Answer (score 1):

For someone who wants to validate specific strings in array:

```
class MyDto {
    @IsIn(['monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday'], { each: true })
    weekdays: string[];

    // regex mask validation
    @Matches('^[a-zA-Z\\s]+$', undefined, { each: true })
    words: string[];

    @Contains('hello', { each: true })
    greetings: string[];
}
```

For custom validation:

```
import {
  ArrayNotEmpty,
  IsArray,
  Validate,
  ValidateNested,
  ValidatorConstraint,
  ValidatorConstraintInterface
} from 'class-validator'

@ValidatorConstraint({ name: 'arrayPrefixValidator' })
export class ArrayPrefixValidator implements ValidatorConstraintInterface {
  validate(values: string[] = []): boolean {
    if (values.length) {
      return values.every((value) => value.startsWith('user-'))
    }
    return false
  }
}

class MyDto {
    // Each item contains a prefix str-
    @Validate(ArrayPrefixValidator, { message: 'No user- prefix' })
    accounts: string[];
}
```

> For more information go to [official docs](https://github.com/typestack/class-validator)